# Calling a Bash function in a while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I made this script which checks to make sure that an offshore script is created. I works ok &emdash; I put in a function to make it a little cleaner. But I don't think that the function works because it keeps on printing out the same time, in seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
check_offshore ()
{
    local RESULTS
    RESULTS=$(ssh -q -T casper@mybox "ls -ltr  /come/and/play/with/us/danny/DropBox| grep foreverr_and_$today.csv")
    rc=$?
}

today=$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d)
time=$(/bin/date +"%T.%3N")
iterate=0
while [ $iterate -le 5 ]
do
     check_offshore
     if [[ $rc != 0 ]] ; then
        echo "$time foreverr_and_$today.csv is not present in casper@mybox:/come/and/play/with/us/danny/DropBox"
        fi
     sleep 5
     iterate=$((iterate+1 ))
     done
```

This is the log that it creates &emdash; the log time never changes. It stays the same, forever and ever and ever until the script stops.

```
17:42:28.380 foreverr_and_20150102.csv is not present in casper@mybox:/come/and/play/with/us/danny/DropBox
17:42:28.380 foreverr_and_20150102.csv is not present in casper@mybox:/come/and/play/with/us/danny/DropBox
17:42:28.380 foreverr_and_20150102.csv is not present in casper@mybox:/come/and/play/with/us/danny/DropBox
17:42:28.380 foreverr_and_20150102.csv is not present in casper@mybox:/come/and/play/with/us/danny/DropBox
17:42:28.380 foreverr_and_20150102.csv is not present in casper@mybox:/come/and/play/with/us/danny/DropBox
17:42:28.380 foreverr_and_20150102.csv is not present in casper@mybox:/come/and/play/with/us/danny/DropBox
```

What's up and how do I fix it?

Comment: Since you don't set `time=$(...)` inside the loop, how do you expect it to change?

Comment: If you're using Bash, you might prefer `for ((iterate = 0; iterate <= 5; iterate++))` to control the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the problem has nothing to do with the function as such; the trouble is in the loop and its immediate surroundings.

Since you don't set `time=$(...)` inside the loop, how do you expect it to change?

Revise the loop so that the time is re-evaluated on each iteration.  Since the date can change if you run this script after something like 23:59:30, you might also want to set the date on each iteration.  You might also use a Bash-specific loop control mechanism:

```
for ((iterate = 0; iterate <= 5; iterate++))
do
    today=$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d)
    time=$(/bin/date +"%T.%3N")
    check_offshore
    if [[ $rc != 0 ]] ; then
       echo "$time foreverr_and_$today.csv is not present in casper@mybox:/come/and/play/with/us/danny/DropBox"
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

You may prefer to stick with the original date, in which case you can continue to set `today` once outside the loop.  Note that your logging becomes a little dubious if things go from 23:59:56.234 to 00:00:02.197 because things took a while just before midnight.  Whether that matters to you or not is a judgement call you'll have to make.  I recommend being unambiguous with the date+time in the log file; it is easier to diagnose what happened when several days later.

Comment: timmy ()
{
time=$(/bin/date +"%Y%m%d-%T.%3N")
}
added a subroutine with the date and time  - thank you